# Laravel 4.2 Custom Pagination Button - custom button for jQuery AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4, pagination

I am using [this](http://www.stillat.com/blog/2014/07/21/creating-a-custom-pagination-view-in-laravel/) tutorial for creating a custom pagination in Laravel 4.2.

I am getting this code for paginating button -

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled">
        <span>«</span>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <span>1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost/car/public/specials?page=2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost/car/public/specials?page=2" rel="next">»</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I need to change the page by clicking on the pagination button by AJAX.

Is it possible?

So, I need to add a AJAX call to all that buttons (dynamically) and remove the ahref codes.

So, it is-

```
<li>
  <a href="http://localhost/car/public/specials?page=2">2</a>
</li>
```

And I want-

```
<li>
  2      <!-- With AJAX call -->
</li>
```

How can I do it?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to your `<a href="http://localhost/car/public/specials?page=2">2</a>` tags e.g. `.page-button` and using jQuery hook into the click event.

`li` should have class:

```
<li>
   <a href="http://localhost/car/public/specials?page=2">2</a>
</li>
```

then

```
$('.page-button').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $url = $(this).attr('href');

     $.ajax({
        'url': $url
     }).done(function(data){
          //handle the response here
     });
)};
```

Comment: I want to add a ID and call according to that ID.

Is it possible?

Comment: IDs are considered unique to each element, if you assign IDs then your hook needs to be duplicated for each of them, hence the easiest solution is to use a `class` name and resolve the required attributes like `href` or `data-*` from the element.

Comment: I need to call different actions on the button ID - Like : if user presses button 1, I need to load page 1 content, if he presses button 5, I need to load page 5's contents.

It is possible?

Comment: If you are using Laravel pagination then passing the `page` in query string is enough, you don't have do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to do it is with [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('.pagination a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#contentWrapper').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

This works well with pagination when swapping out some content with another chunk of results from the paginator. `#contentWrapper` here would be a `div` surrounding the paginated content.

If you need to perform some further logic after the `.load()` call, you can use the `complete` callback like so:

```
$('.pagination a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#contentWrapper').load($(this).attr('href'), function () {
    //do something here
  });
});
```